# Rendering 3 images at a time with Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I have a page with infinite scrolling.  The page initially loads with 3  tags.  Each section contains 3 product images (not just images, also product information) pulled from my database. The underscore template would be like such:

```
<section>
  <div class='left'>
    <img src="{{ product.src }}" />
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    <div class='top'>
      <img src="{{ product.src }}" />
    </div>
    <div class='bottom'>
      <img src="{{ product.src }}" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I'm having trouble thinking how to render this.  I'm thinking a product would probably be a Backbone Model:

```
var ProductModel = Backbone.Model.extends({
  defaults: {
    src: '',
    title: 'Product'
    brand: 'ABC'
  }
});
```

Then the next part I got stuck.  In my mind, collections are like lists of data.  However, in this scenario, I don't want a whole list of products displayed, I only want 3 products.  Then what about the View?  Should the view render all 3 images at a go or should they render one image at a time (like call render 3 times)?  Do keep in mind that I still need to render the other 2 sections (and all of them show different products).

Should I control my HTTP GET call to only respond with 3 images at a time OR should I just let it return all products?

Could someone please help me or point me to some examples of similar use-cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a Collection for Products, a Model for Product, A view for the page and then a view for each product. The idea is to fetch a collection from the page view, and then loop through it to render each Product.

The advantage of having a view for each product is that you can easily assign events (like a click event) on each product.

The amount of images you get from an HTTP GET depends on the use and overhead. You might want to consider adding a variable in your API so that the application controls how much images you get in the reply.

Have a look at this [example](http://backbonetutorials.com/infinite-scrolling/) that includes infinite scrolling and backbone.